# Why doesn't Compute VM COS metadata not get carry over to "Equivalent command line"?

Tags: google-container-os, google-cloud-compute-engine

I'm deploying a container to a Container Optimized OS or COS on Google Compute.
I want to specify Logging and Monitoring for the VM.  There are 2 ways to do this:

- Specify metadata flags:

  [image: screenshot]
- Mark the checkboxes

  [image: screenshot]

But when I then click on "Equivalent command line", there's no indication of these options.

Am I just misinterpreting something here or am I not allowed to specify these flags in the command?

I tried with the non-COS VM instance and the expected metadata flag showed up to indicate the metadata.  But this does not show up in the COS command.

```bash
gcloud compute instances create instance-1 \
    ...
    --metadata=MY_TEST_FLAG=test_value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When using container optimized OS images while creating a VM this issue is coming, But this is for command line code only. REST equivalent is generated properly, As a work around for this you can add the metadata flag to the generated command as mentioned below.

```
--metadata=google-logging-enabled=true,google-monitoring-enabled=true
```

I have raised a request on this issue. Please monitor the [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/262303519) for further updates on the fix of the issue.

In case you find any such issues in future you can report to Google using [Report issues and request features with issue trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).